# TRIM BOTH Teradata not working for single quotes

Tags: teradata, trim

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH 'a' FROM 'aaaaaaaaaaaaasdfasa');
```

works fine and returns sdfas
but I am trying to remove quotes, so I did

```
 SELECT TRIM(BOTH ''' FROM (''2565','5216','5364'') ;
```

I get error - Query ends within a string or comment block. Please suggest how to do this

Comment: You must double a single quote within a string: *SELECT Trim(Both '''' FROM ('''2565'',''5216'',''5364'''))` but this is not what you actually need/want. How does the parameter exactly look like?

Comment: I have @Group parameter which will either be ''2565','5216','5364'' or '2565,5216,5364'. As for WHERE IN clause both (2565,5216,5364) or ('2565','5216','5364') will work. Challenge is to remove quotes, either all quotes or the enclosing ones.

Comment: You may recommend any other function which could help solve the issue

Comment: So this is part of a stored procedure?

Comment: There is a .NET application through which we run SQLs in Teradata. We can pass parameters. Cannot create stored procs.

Comment: Is this passed as a parameter to a Prepared SQL statement or a part of a Dynamic SQL statement. Are the outer quotes actually part of the param?  `'2565,5216,5364'` or `2565,5216,5364`?

Comment: I'm still a little vague on what you want, but it looks to me like you want to replace two single quotes with one single quote?  I'd handle that in your .NET code.

Comment: @dnoeth, outer quotes are added by .NET application. I can pass those params as 2565,5216,5364, which creates '2565,5216,5364' OR as '2565','5216','5364', which create ''2565','5216','5364'' in Teradata. Either way I need to remove the two enclosing quotes.

Comment: @Andrew, I have no control over the .NET application. It is enterprise wide application

Comment: Well, then you may be in trouble.  Teradata cannot handle a string like that.  I don't think any RDBMS can.  Any string like `''foo''` is going to result in an error.

Comment: If it's actually passed as `'2565,5216,5364'` you can use your inital approach: `WHERE Position (Cast(group_id AS VARCHAR(5)) IN '2565,5216,5364' ) > 0`. But you might need to code for avoiding false positives: `WHERE Position (','||Cast(group_id AS VARCHAR(5))||',' IN ',' || '2565,5216,5364' || ',') > 0` to avoid matching `256`

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the .NET application successfully inserts data and the issue is at the time of `SELECT` or `UPDATE` i.e. the issue is not in a prepared SQL statement used within the .NET application. This also assumes that data sanity checks for using such logic in `WHERE .. IN` are already in place.

Assume your data values are:

```
2565,5216,5364
'2565','5216','5364'
```

Your application coverts these into following:

```
'2565,5216,5364'
''2565','5216','5364''
```

For ease of query design for this answer, we can convert these to string values for SQL by escaping each single quote in the value with an additional single quote, and then putting the entire thing inside a pair of single quotes to make it a string; which gives us:

```
'''2565,5216,5364'''
'''''2565'',''5216'',''5364'''''
```

If you want to remove all single quotes in these, you can use

```
SELECT OREPLACE( '''2565,5216,5364''', '''', '');
SELECT OREPLACE( '''''2565'',''5216'',''5364''''', '''', '');
```

Which means replace all single quotes with empty strings and gives us:

```
2565,5216,5364
2565,5216,5364
```

This may be the way to go in case you are comparing with integer values.

Now if you want your data to be preserved and remove only the enclosing quotes put by the .NET application, (e.g. if the comparison is also with character data) then you can combine this with further logic. Let us use the second data value, since it present more value for such an operation

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '''' FROM '''''2565'',''5216'',''5364''''');
```

The query above will give you following results which removes the enclosing quotes from application but also removes the first and the last quotes entered by the user

```
2565','5216','5364
```

A better option, but with the assumption that you application *always* encloses the data in quotes will be

```
SELECT SUBSTR('''''2565'',''5216'',''5364''''',2,CHARACTER_LENGTH('''''2565'',''5216'',''5364''''')-2);
```

This will perform substring operation from second character in the string till length-2, and will thus ignore both quotes inserted by the application

```
'2565','5216','5364'
```